# Karma "not found" in NetBeans after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: javascript, netbeans, karma-runner, osx-yosemite

I have a WAR project in NetBeans which uses Karma with Jasmine to unit-test the JavaScript files. The platform is Mac OS X. Things worked as they should under Mavericks, but after I upgraded to Yosemite, it no longer works, with the error message :

```
Failed to execute goal com.kelveden:maven-karma-plugin:1.8:start (default) on project Insight-war: There was an error executing Karma. Cannot run program "karma" (in directory "/Users/thja/Documents/Projects/kpi2010_core/WebGIS/Insight-war"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

It tries to execute the following command, as printed in the log:

```
karma start /Users/thja/Documents/Projects/kpi2010_core/WebGIS/Insight-war/src/main/webapp/config/karma.conf.js --browsers PhantomJS --reporters dots,junit --single-run --no-auto-watch --colors true
```

I can run the exact same command in the Terminal without a problem - it executes and give the test results. `which karma` gives the result `/usr/local/bin/karma`, and `/usr/local/bin` is part of the global PATH.

Is there any fix one can do for this, or do I just have to post an issue at the Maven Karma Plugin page?

Platform:

- Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite.
- NetBeans 8.0.1
- maven-karma-plugin 1.8
- Java 1.7.0_45

Comment: Can you execute the Maven command from command line as well?

Comment: @ladar If I build the project with command line `mvn install`, it works as expected, and runs the Karma tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to Yosemite turning off /etc/launchd.conf, so NetBeans doesn't get the correct PATH variable - so not directly related to Karma.

I fixed it by setting `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin` in netbeans.conf (within the NetBeans app package). Then the karma part of the build script runs successfully within NetBeans.